# Python: How to use platform.win32_ver() on a remote machine?

Tags: python, windows

So of course I'm new to Python and to programming in general...
I am trying to get OS version information from the network. For now I only care about the windows machines.

using PyWin32 I can get some basic information, but it's not very reliable. This is an example of what I am doing right now: win32net.NetWkstaGetInfo(myip, 100)

However, it appears as though this would provide me with more appropriate information: platform.win32_ver()

I have no idea how get the info from a remote machine using this. I need to specify an IP or a range of IP's... I intend on using Google's ipaddr to get a list of network ranges to scan. I will eventually need to scan a large network for this info.

Can someone provide an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use remote registry...
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion

ProductName, EditionID, CurrentVersion, CurrentBuild

Answer (score 1):

A good way is to use WMI.  The following links from Microsoft contain enough information to write code for your purposes:

- [Connecting to WMI on a Remote Computer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389290(v=VS.85).aspx)
- [WMI Tasks: Operating Systems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394596(VS.85).aspx)

The missing piece is how to do this in Python.  For that, consult Tim Golden's site:

- [WMI for Python](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/)
- [WMI Cookbook](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/cookbook.html)

By the way, if you're OK with using a command line program and parsing the output, then I would suggest the [PsTools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx) available freely.  In particular, [psinfo](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897550.aspx) can do what you want.

Comment: will only work if you have access rights to the remote computers

Comment: assume that I have at least "user" rights on a PC. 99.99% I should have admin rights. I will not have admin rights to any server, only to the PC's.

Comment: still looking at and trying to understand WMI. Very promising!

Comment: Does the WMI service need to be enabled for me to use this? If so, I cannot use this solution. There is a department where due to a specific application they had to disable the service.

Comment: @Chris: unfortunately, it needs to be enabled.